# Call/SMS logs in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calllog

Kindly read before downvote my Question I know that this question has asked may times. I want to get count/time/duration of incoming and outgoing calls and sms in my application. I have searched a lot, but got same answer (not possible at least for non jailbroken devices).Than I found a solution:[Link](https://iosstuff.wordpress.com/2011/08/19/accessing-iphone-call-history/)  but no luck with iOS5 and onwards.

Although there are application like "Spyzie" [Spyzie video url:](https://youtu.be/CbT9zwylrhg?list=PLYPK1oRp9mJ8o_6Kba9UC_F9hgfOOcJEl) which provide the same services. So there are any other way to get from iCloud or somewhere else. ?

Your help and suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Their website seems to indicate that they're pulling this from icloud data, where you're required to configure an icloud backup on the phone to get this to work.

Comment: @petesh Thanks. is there any way to get iCloud data in application ?

Comment: You don't have access to the local data - how they accomplish appears to be by downloading the data from the icloud (using the customer supplied icloud username and password). so if you were to attempt to accomplish this in your own app you would need to get the user to provide their icloud username and password and download the backups locally, and then extract the data from the backup.